# Unable to execute a python script after pip install the package

Tags: python, pip

I created a python package looking like the following. The package is primarily used to run stages in a jenkins pipeline inside a docker container. So I created a repository in github and created a dockerfile with a step where the repository is cloned and performed pip install on that package. Then I built the docker image.

```
jenkins_pipeline_pkg/
| - jenkins_pipeline_pkg/
    | - __init__.py
| - config/
    | - config.yaml
| - scripts/
    | - pre_build.py
    | - build.py
| - setup.py
```

I performed pip install on the package inside the docker container I created using the dockerfile. The setup.py looks like the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='jenkins_pipeline_pkg',
      version='0.1',
      description='Scripts for jenkins pipeline',
      url='<private repo url>',
      author='<name>',
      author_email='<email>',
      packages=['jenkins_pipeline_pkg'],
      zip_safe=False,
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'pre-build = jenkins_pipeline_pkg.pre_build:main',
              'build = jenkins_pipeline_pkg.build:main',],
      }
)
```

I ran pip install on the package. It installed the executable mentioned in the entry_points in `~/.local/bin`. Then I tried to execute the executable from anywhere else by not changing into the directory `~/.local/bin` (just say I executed from /home/user). And also bash auto complete doesnt show the pre-build command. I dont know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Try either creating link for executable in /use/bin or include ~/.local/bin in $PATH. Hope this will help

Comment: Added export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Great. You are welcome. I will copy paste same as answer.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this for every user who pip installs the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either creating link for executable in /use/bin or include ~/.local/bin in $PATH.

Edit:
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH